# How to get refresh token which is saved with http only cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm bulding .net core application consists of two parts. Backend api and frontend. And i want to use jwt token for authentication. I read on Stackoverflow that it's best to save access token into memory but keep refresh token in secure and http only cookie. I have completed most of configuration but i don't understand how to pass refresh token to frontend (javascript client) (after page refresh)

I thought maybe i can create ajax request which goes to controller and get refresh token from session cookie but i'm not sure if its correct way.

**My question is :** How can i pass refresh token which saved in httponly to frontend javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

A better suggestion is that save the token into client. If you use session to save token, the size of memory is limited when saving many tokens. Jwt authentication has a cookie configuration which can get it from cookie automatically.

```
   services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(config=>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "auth";
                config.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;//The cookie cannot be obtained by the front-end or the browser, and can only be modified on the server side
                config.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;//This cookie cannot be used as a third-party cookie under any circumstances, without exception. For example, suppose b.com sets the following cookies:
            })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            //...
        }
```

When sending a token or refresh the token, you can create the token as this.

```
  public IActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        //...
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        Response.Cookies.Append("auth",tokenString);

        return Ok(tokenString);
    }
```

About refreshing token, the new token will replace the old token only when the key is same. Considering using ajax, you can pass the expire time to client, and add a listen event using javascript. If it will expire, you can trigger a function to request the token with ajax.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. So in this method we save jwt token into cookie right ? I read that we should keep access token in memory object (in frontent javascript) but refresh token in cookie. And the reason for this if somebody steals token from cookie they can use it but if somebody steals refresh token they need to get token and when he send request to get access token on behalf of original user (with some attack) response for refresh token returns back to original browser not to attacker so he cannot get access key.

Comment: You can use HttpOnly and SameSite to ensure the security, in addition, there is a sha encryption key to ensure the security of the token.

Comment: Yes. But method above saves token's itself to cookie right ?

Comment: The cookie is configured in the starup,  so it dependent on the configuration.

Comment: But if i save save token into cookie with httpOnly mark i cannot get it from front end. In my case i will call backend api with this token with every request. I have two apps from first one i get token then i show token to 2. one (which is front end) at that moment if frontend server saves information to httpOnly cookie i will never will be able to get it back. ( unless i get values by ajax query which was reason for this question. I just wanted to learn if this is acceptable method. )

Comment: Why do you receive the token in front end, what is the function you received in front end?

Comment: Hello, because i need to send it with every request to api. As i read i learnt new way.think i will do this way please correct me if this is wrong method. First i will send request to backend and get token after i get token i will send this token to frontend application after token is verified i will create cookie with http only and save refresh key to inside but i will allow this cookie to be send to backend api. so without when i send request to backend to refresh my token my backend app can see my refresh token from cookie.

Comment: You have save the token in a cookie, every request will carry the cookie, if you still want to get the token through javascript, I suggest that you can return the token as a json in the bakend.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is it common practice ? Most important is it safe ? When client's browser visit somewhere else this cookie will not be send to them right ?

Comment: This is the same as the purpose of obtaining the token from the cookie. The token itself is an encrypted string, and its password is on the server side. Its security depends on whether your server is secure. About the last question, if the customer still visits this site page, cookie will be send to them.